# Django 2.1.3 reset password link not displaying

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

After upgrading to Django 2.1.3, I noticed the "Forgotten your password or username?" link was missing from the admin login page. After some investigating, I found the that the `django.contrib.auth.urls.py` module used the name `password_reset` for the reset url, while in the `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html` template the url was named `admin_password_reset`:

**django.contrib.auth.urls.py (line 16)**

```
path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
```

**django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html (starting at line 54)**

```
{% url 'admin_password_reset' as password_reset_url %}
{% if password_reset_url %}
<div class="password-reset-link">
<a href="{{ password_reset_url }}">{% trans 'Forgotten your password or username?' %}</a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

When I changed `admin_password_reset` to `password_reset` in Django's `login.html`, the link showed up on the login page and worked as expected.

In my `urls.py` I have:

```
path('lodging/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

My project has no other modifications to the authentication system. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Update**

I checked out one of my older Django projects (v1.11) and the same thing exists: `login.html` shows `admin_password_reset` and `auth.urls` shows `password_reset`. Also, the "Forgot password" link doesn't display on the login page. Further, "grepping" for `admin_password_reset` in all the Django source code only returns the `login.html` file.

So for sure I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry @AwesomeGeek, I honestly can't remember. I would look but I don't remember what project this was for. I do a lot of small projects for websites.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on django 3.
Different versions of django need a different code but fundamentally they all just need you to specify the url for admin_password_reset

Here is what worked for me for django 3:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'admin_password_reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='admin_password_reset')
]
```